# RSQLite - Store date columns as character in SQLite

Tags: r, rsqlite

Is there a way how I can store dates in R data frame as character strings in SQLite using RSQLite? Currently, date columns are stored as integers. I can probably cast all dates to  strings before writing to SQLite, but as I need to write to SQLite from function where data frame is one of arguments I would prefer to avoid such transformation.

```
library('RSQLite')

df <- data.frame(
        x=1:3, 
        y=as.Date(c('2011-01-01','2011-03-03','2011-12-31'))
      )

df

# Create connection and temporary database
sqlite <- dbDriver("SQLite")
tmpdb  <- dbConnect(sqlite,"__this_is_temporary_db__.db")           

# Write data    
dbWriteTable(tmpdb,'df',df)

# We get integers from date
dbGetQuery(tmpdb,'select * from df')

dbDisconnect(tmpdb)      

# file.remove('__this_is_temporary_db__.db')
```

Comment: See https://github.com/rstats-db/RSQLite/issues/17

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should coerce to character. You can do it for all data.frame date columns using something like this:

```
ll <- lapply(df,function(x) 
     if(inherits (x,c('POSIXct','Date'))
       as.character(x)
     else x))
do.call(rbind.data.frame,ll)
```

Comment: ...the main reason being that sqlite does not have a native [date type](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). And R stores dates internally as integers. So if you want character, you have to send it to sqlite that way.

Comment: And when you force a text field, e.g. with `dbSendQuery(tmpdb, "CREATE TABLE df (x INTEGER,  y TEXT )"); dbSendPreparedQuery(tmpdb,"INSERT into df values ( ?, ?)",bind.data=df)` it gets converted to a real-lookalike text.

Comment: @agstudy It is still not correct. Current vesion returns data frame with 3 columns and 2 rows. I think the correct version should be: `df[] <- lapply(df,function(x) if(inherits (x,c('POSIXct','Date'))) as.character(x) else x)`